# Python: Change value in dataframe column w.r.t variable value and other column value as well

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

have got input dataframe like below and a variable '`extra`'

**input_df**

```
Item    Space   refill      Min     Max
Apple   0.25    12.53       0.125   0.25
Lemon   0.25    11.2        0.25    0.375       
Potato  0.375   10.3        0.375   0.75
Melon   0.375   9.2         0.25    0.75
```

'`extra`' variable can be negative or positive.

Expected **output_df** if `extra = 0.25`
(this extra 0.25 space need to be splitted in the multiples of 0.125 and added to items with higher refill order. In this case, 0.125 + 0.125 = 0.25 so two items space will be updated. Also should consider Max value here, on adding space it should not exceed Max value, if happens skip that item and move to next.)

```
Item    Space   refill      Min     Max
Apple   0.25    12.53       0.125   0.25        #item skipped since it exceeds Max limit if extra space added
Lemon   0.375   11.2        0.25    0.375       #0.125 from extra space added here
Potato  0.5     10.3        0.375   0.75        #remaining 0.125 from extra space added here
Melon   0.375   9.2         0.25    0.75        #no more space to be added
```

Expected **output_df** if `extra = -0.25`
(this extra -0.25 space[which is two times of -0.125] need to be reduced from items with higher refill. Also should consider Min Value here, on reducing space it should not go below Min value, if happens skip that item and move to next.)

```
Item    Space   refill      Min     Max
Apple   0.125   12.53       0.125   0.25        #-0.125 from extra space reduced here
Lemon   0.25    11.2        0.25    0.375       #item skipped since it doesn't satisfy Min limit if reduced
Potato  0.375   10.3        0.375   0.75        #item skipped since it doesn't satisfy Min limit if reduced
Melon   0.25    9.2         0.25    0.75        #rem -0.125 from extra space reduced here
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

1. Both `extra` and the values in columns `Min` and `Max` should *always* contain multiples of `0.125`. E.g. `df.Min % 0.125` should always lead to a series of *zeros*.
2. The `df` index contains *unique* values only. If this is not yet the case, use `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)` to reset it. Or use `drop=False`, if you want to keep the original index values. You can then reset them afterwards, using `df.set_index('index', drop=True, inplace=True)`.

Given the assumptions, the following should achieve this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'Item': {0: 'Apple', 1: 'Lemon', 2: 'Potato', 3: 'Melon'}, 
        'Space': {0: 0.25, 1: 0.25, 2: 0.375, 3: 0.375}, 
        'refill': {0: 12.53, 1: 11.2, 2: 10.3, 3: 9.2}, 
        'Min': {0: 0.125, 1: 0.25, 2: 0.375, 3: 0.25}, 
        'Max': {0: 0.25, 1: 0.375, 2: 0.75, 3: 0.75}}

def f(df, extra):
    length = int(abs(extra/0.125))
    repeats = np.repeat([0.125 * -1 if np.signbit(extra) else 0.125], len(df))

    tmp = np.where((pd.Series(repeats).lt(0) & df.Space.gt(df.Min)) | 
             (pd.Series(repeats).gt(0) & df.Space.lt(df.Max)), 
             df.Space.add(repeats), df.Space)
    
    new_series = np.where(df.Space.ne(tmp).cumsum().gt(length), df.Space, tmp)
    return new_series
```

Function applied:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Space = f(df, 0.25)

print(df)

     Item  Space  refill    Min    Max
0   Apple  0.250   12.53  0.125  0.250
1   Lemon  0.375   11.20  0.250  0.375
2  Potato  0.500   10.30  0.375  0.750
3   Melon  0.375    9.20  0.250  0.750

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Space = f(df, -0.25)

print(df)

     Item  Space  refill    Min    Max
0   Apple  0.125   12.53  0.125  0.250
1   Lemon  0.250   11.20  0.250  0.375
2  Potato  0.375   10.30  0.375  0.750
3   Melon  0.250    9.20  0.250  0.750
```

Suppose we use `extra= 0.375`, then the last item will also change:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Space = f(df, 0.375)

print(df)

     Item  Space  refill    Min    Max
0   Apple  0.250   12.53  0.125  0.250
1   Lemon  0.375   11.20  0.250  0.375
2  Potato  0.500   10.30  0.375  0.750
3   Melon  0.500    9.20  0.250  0.750 # also changed
```

**Explanation**:

- Inside function `f`, we first create an `np.array` named `repeats` with a length equal to your `df`, filled either with `-0.125` or `0.125`, depending on the sign of `extra` (using [`np.signbit`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.signbit.html)).
- Next, we use [`np.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) and check either (values in column `Space` < 0 *and* > values in column `Min`) or (values in column `Space` > 0 *and* < values in column `Max`). For each `True` we want `df.Space.add(repeats)`, for each `False` we keep the values from `df.Space`. We store the result in a variable `tmp`. See [`Series.lt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.lt.html) and [`Series.gt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html).
- Finally, we apply `np.where` again to limit the amount of changes to be made. In order to figure this out, we first apply [`Series.ne`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html) to `tmp` and get `True` for each mismatch (i.e. a change). Applying [`Series.cumsum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) will get us a cumulative sum of all the `True` values. Once, a value inside this series becomes greater than `int(abs(extra/0.125))` we need to stop making changes. So, from that point onwards, we fall back on the original values in column `Space`.

Comment: Your assumption is right! Will work it out and let you know shortly. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I'm getting 'ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (105,) (99,) (99,)' on calculating 'tmp'. The original dataframe shape is 99 but shape of result on calculating 'tmp' using np.where comes 105. Kindly guide me through this.

Comment: No other operations added in between. Value on extra is -0.125. And this error occurs in first np.where(), result of it is somehow coming longer than df.Space. But shape of df passed is 99 only.

Comment: I think I know why this is happening: your actual `df` will probably have duplicate index values. Before using `df.Space = f(df, -0.125)`, you want to reset the index: `df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)`. Or use `drop=False` if you want to keep the original index values. You can then use `df.set_index('index', drop=True, inplace=True)` after the function call to get it back as the index.

Comment: Perfect! You saved my day. Thank You! That's the issue, after resetting index it worked fine.

Comment: Excellent! You're welcome, and good luck with your project! I'll update the answer with the comment that the index needs to contain unique values.